# How to make a module constant also visible within an eigenclass?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, eigenclass

I created a module that contains a constant `NAME` and a method `hello`. If a class includes the module, both definitions should be visible in different scope.

```
module A
  NAME = 'Otto'
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  def hello(name = 'world')
    self.class.hello(name)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def hello(name = 'world')
      "Hello #{name}!"
    end
  end
end

class B
  include A

  def instance_scope
    p [__method__, hello(NAME)]
  end

  def self.class_scope
    p [__method__, hello(NAME)]
  end

  class << self
    def eigen_scope
      p [__method__, hello(NAME)]
    end
  end
end

B.new.instance_scope
B.class_scope
B.eigen_scope

#=> script.rb:34:in `eigen_scope': uninitialized constant Class::NAME (NameError)
    from script.rb:41
```

But the the constant isn't visible in the instance method scope of the eigenclass, `class << self`.

Is there a way to make the module more robust and provide the constants also in the errorneous scope above?

Comment: Thanks for the interesting question. I learned something new!

Comment: @EricDuminil Not at all! Your explanation is very useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solution

```
class << self
  def eigen_scope
    p [__method__, hello(self::NAME)]
    #=> [:eigen_scope, "Hello Otto!"]
  end
end
```

## Why does `self::NAME` work?

- `A::NAME` would be the easiest, hard-coded version.
- `B::NAME` would also work, because `B` includes `A`
- Inside `eigen_scope`, `self` is `B`, so `self::NAME` works as well
- `self::NAME` would also work in `self.class_scope`
- `self::NAME` wouldn't work in `instance_scope` : a `B` instance is not a class/module.

## Why doesn't `NAME` work?

[Here](https://cirw.in/blog/constant-lookup.html)'s a very good explanation.

> constant lookup searches for constants that are defined in
>   `Module.nesting`, `Module.nesting.first.ancestors`, and
>   `Object.ancestors` if `Module.nesting.first` is nil or a module

`self` is the same in `class_scope` and `eigen_scope`.

`Module.nesting` is different though :

- `[B]` for `class_scope`
- `[#<Class:B>, B]` for `eigen_scope`

So `Module.nesting.first.ancestors` is :

- `[B, A, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]` for `class_scope`
- `[#<Class:B>, A::ClassMethods, #<Class:Object>, #<Class:BasicObject>, Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]` for `eigen_scope`

`A` isn't searched, but `A::ClassMethods`!

So you could define :

```
module A
  module ClassMethods
    NAME = 'Bob'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your explaination. Is there a way to adapt the module so that `hello_name(NAME)` also works within the eigenclass?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: any ideas why constant lookup works such weird in this case? inside the class_scope it works pretty well, but `self` is the same in both cases?